# React Native: Error while running the android app

Tags: android, android-emulator, react-native

When running the android app in react native i'm geeting this error

> Execution failed for task ':react-native-contacts:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\New folder contains a valid JDK installation.

I have also checked the java version it is installted. My java version is 1.8.0_151.

Comment: Do you use `react-native-maps` ?

Comment: no i'm just running the app .

Comment: i download it from github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add Jdk path `org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_144` to `gradle.properties` file and then run this command line in your projects root

`cd android && gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android`

Comment: Now i'm getting this error Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE